# [SwiftUI]: ForEach is not working for array of dictionary, dictionary with array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swiftui, swiftui-list

I try to iterate through array in SwiftUI, but it is not working fine.

My code:

```
let arr_type2  = [
                    ["type":"Temperature","Units":["°C","°F","°K"]],
                    ["type":"Length","Units":["m","km","ft","yd","mi"]],
                    ["type":"Time","Units":["sec","min","hr","day"]],
                    ["type":"Volume","Units":["ml","lt","cups","pints","gallons"]]
                    ]

ForEach(arr_type2, id: \.self) { dict in //Error
        Text("")
}
```

Error: Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Hashable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols

I just started learning SwiftUI, can you please help me to save this?

Thank you for your valuable time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it cleanly with

```
struct Model:Hashable {
    let type:String
    let unnits:[String]
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let arr_type2 = [Model(type:"Temperature", unnits: ["°C","°F","°K"])]

    var body: some View {
           ForEach(arr_type2, id: \.self) { item in

            Text(item.type)
        }
    }
}
```

For why check https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-does-self-work-for-foreach

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ForEach` like this

```
 var body: some View {
    let arr_type2  = [
        ["type":"Temperature","Units":["°C","°F","°K"]],
        ["type":"Length","Units":["m","km","ft","yd","mi"]],
        ["type":"Time","Units":["sec","min","hr","day"]],
        ["type":"Volume","Units":["ml","lt","cups","pints","gallons"]]
    ]

    return ForEach(0..<arr_type2.count, id: \.self) { index -> AnyView in
        let units = arr_type2[index]["Units"] as! [String]
        return AnyView(VStack {
            Text(arr_type2[index]["type"] as! String)
            ForEach(0..<units.count, id: \.self) { indexUnits in
                 Text(units[indexUnits])
            }

        })
    }

}
```

Comment: it shows error like "Ambiguous reference to member 'count'"

Comment: @NiravPatel Please see my edit, this displays "type" from each dictionary, tested in Xcode 11.3

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot what was wrong before?
also, how can I iterate through Units after that with same ForEach?

Comment: @NiravPatel The problem in your approach is that type of arr_type2 have to be Hashable (Dictionary is not Hashable). "Units" are arrays, so you need another ForEach to iterate them, see my edited answer